# Grouped stacked barplot ggplot2 without facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, stacked-chart

Hi I wanted to make a stacked barplot using ggplot2 with below data:

```
    DF <- read.table(text="Rank   P_Rank    value_Rank     P2_Rank
                             AC      1        250             1
                             AN      1        100             1
                             AT      1        155             1
                             CA      1        90              1
                             CG      2        630             1
                             CN      2        150             1
                             CT      2        384             1
                             GA      2        485             1
                             CA      3        94              1 
                             AT      3        75              1
                             GN      3        163             1
                             GT      3        97              1
                             CA      4        63              2
                             CG      4        16              2
                             CT      4        140             2
                             CG      4        610             2
                             CN      5        46              2
                             CT      5        330             2
                             GA      5        150             2
                             CA      5        67              2 
                             CG      6        130             2
                             CN      6        250             2
                             CT      6        484             2
                             GA      6        185             2", header=TRUE)

ggplot(DF, aes(x = as.factor(P_Rank), y = value_Rank, fill = Rank)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

I obtained this barplot but I would like to group stacked bars depending on the variable "P2_Rank". In red what I would like to add (I have no preference for the 2 versions of barplots A or B because it responds to my needs).

[image]

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Update.* Turns out I didn't read your post carefully -- I just noticed you said "without facet_grid" in your title.  I'm going to leave this here anyway, but the upvoter should feel free to remove the vote.

---

You can try faceting:

```
ggplot(DF, 
  aes(x = as.factor(P_Rank), y = value_Rank, fill = Rank)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_wrap(~ P2_Rank, scales = "free_x", switch = "x") +
  scale_x_discrete("P2_Rank", labels = NULL) +
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
        panel.margin = unit(-1, "lines"))
```

Output:
[image]